# TYPO3: TypoScript doesn't work after upgrade 4.2 to 4.5

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm upgrading my typo3 installation from 4.2 to 4.5 and after that my content is no more visible on my page.
I used a marker

```
<!--###MAINCONTENT###-->
```

in my template file and had the following typoScript code to fill it with my content:

```
page = PAGE

page.10 {
  template = FILE
  template.file = fileadmin/Templates/clean.tmpl
  marks.MAINCONTENT < styles.content.get
}
```

but it don't work now. What can i do?

Comment: Did you do the upgrade sequentially from 4.2 > 4.3 > 4.4 > 4.5? And: Do you just get a blank page or is the template displayed?

Comment: `###MAINCONTENT###` marker is substituted with your conetnt, but your marker is inside HTML comments, so I can assume, that your content is output this way: `<!-- your content goes here -->`. So it is not visible on page, but it should be inside code. Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the static ts templates are included or not!